# Bootstrap4-NPM start error

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, npm-scripts

I am learning to automate web development tasks using npm scripts.

Below is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:all",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss": "onchange 'css/*.scss' --npm run scss",
    "watch:all": "parallelshell 'npm run watch:scss' 'npm run lite'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
     "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
     "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
     "onchange": "^3.3.0",
     "parallelshell": "^3.0.2"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
     "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
   }
}
```

However, when I run `npm start` in the command prompt I encounter the following  error:

**Error message:**

> `D:\encypher technologies\Bootstrap4-starter\Bootstrap4\conFusion>npm start`
>
> `confusion@1.0.0 start D:\encypher technologies\Bootstrap4-starter\Bootstrap4\conFusion`
>
> `npm run watch:all`
>
> `confusion@1.0.0 watch:all D:\encypher technologies\Bootstrap4-starter\Bootstrap4\conFusion`
>
> `parallelshell 'npm run watch:scss' 'npm run lite'`
>
> `'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
>
> `'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
>
> `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`
>
> `'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.`
>
> `'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
>
> `'lite'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
>
> `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`
>
> `npm ERR! errno 1`
>
> `npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 watch:all: 'parallelshell 'npm run watch:scss' 'npm run lite'`
>
> `npm ERR! Exit status 1`
>
> `npm ERR!`
>
> `npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 watch:all script.`
>
> `npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`
>
> `npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`
>
> `npm ERR!     C:\Users\NIKHIL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_log\2018-01-08T11_13_45_703Z-debug.log`
>
> `npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600`
>
> `npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\NIKHIL\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"`
>
> `npm ERR! node v8.9.3`
>
> `npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12`
>
> `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`
>
> `npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 start: 'npm run watch:all'`
>
> `npm ERR! Exit status 1`
>
> `npm ERR!`
>
> `npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 start script 'npm run watch:all'.`
>
> `npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the confusion package,`
>
> `npm ERR! not with npm itself.`
>
> `npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:`
>
> `npm ERR! npm run watch:all`
>
> `npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:`
>
> `npm ERR! npm bugs confusion`
>
> `npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:`
>
> `npm ERR!`
>
> `npm ERR! npm owner ls confusion`
>
> `npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.`
>
> `npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR! D:\encypher technologies\Bootstrap4-starter\Bootstrap4\conFusion\npm-debug.log`

Comment: let try command:

npm run dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using Windows. The Windows command line doesn't like single quotes in package.json. Use `\"` instead.

```
"watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss",
"watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""
```

You were also missing the space between `--` and `npm`.